# How to find the date of the xth day in the yth month of a year?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using Python's datetime module for dates.

I'd like to be able to get a datetime for the (say) 3rd Wednesday in May of a given year.

Is there an easy way of doing this without significant external dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_derired_date(day_number,day,month,year):
  day = day.upper()
  month_dict={
  "MONDAY":0,
  "TUESDAY":1,
  "WEDNESDAY":2,
  "THURSDAY":3,
  "FRIDAY":4,
  "SATURDAY":5,
  "SUNDAY":6
  }
  datestring = "{0}-{1}".format(year,month)
  dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m')
  first_day_of_month = datetime(dt.year, dt.month, 1)
  month_diff_value = month_dict[day]
  final_date = first_day_of_month + timedelta(days=((month_diff_value-calendar.monthrange(dt.year,dt.month)[0])+7)%7)
  return final_date
```

get_derired_date(1,"Friday",2,2016)